# Why does the split function with multiple separators behaves differently than the -split option?

Tags: string, powershell, split

I have the following string :

```
PS C:\> $toto = "0  10.20.24.14"
```

When calling the `split(' +')` function, it behaves like this :

```
PS C:\> $toto.split(' +')
0

10.20.24.14
```

But when using the the `-split' +'` , it behaves like this :

```
PS C:\> $toto -split ' +'
0
10.20.24.14
```

Why does the split function with multiple separators behaves differently than the -split option ?

Comment: `-split ' +'` uses regex for splitting and ` +` is taking as much space as it can to perform the split. `.Split( )` doesn't know what regex is and is just splitting in every appearance of a single space.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thanks. Can you please convert your comment to an anwser ?

Comment: There is no need for that as this question is a duplicate of another question.